# How can I update list of strings as fields of document in firestore using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone explain me how can I update list of fields in firestore document using flutter. For example, I have document with field named as uid. When I press button in my APP I want to add more uids as fields in this document, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can not update List in document

You can follow below steps:

1. Get list from document.
2. Add whatever you want to add.
3. Update whole list in document.

**Example**

```
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await users.doc(docId).get();
    List<String> namesList = List.from(doc.data()['names']);
    namesList.add("Priyesh");
    namesList.removeAt(1);
    await users.doc(docId).update({
       'name' : namesList
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you give me any example please?

Comment: I've updated my answer so please check it. And approve the answer if it works.